# Symfony2 composer.json "repositories" — What is driving the fetched Version?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to use the twitter/bootstrap repository without taking advantage of http://packagist.org. The below `composer.json` works fine to get the tag `2.1.1`, but as you can see, I've referenced version `2.1.1` 3 times. This seems overly redundant. My question is :

**What variable is driving the the desired version of bootstrap repo to be fetched?** Should I be using master somewhere then only `2.1.1` in on other place?

- Is it the `"require": { "twitter/bootstrap": "2.1.1" }`?
- Is it the `"version": "2.1.1"`?
- Is it the `"reference": "v2.1.1"`?

`composer.json` snip below:

```
"require": {
        "twitter/bootstrap": "2.1.1"
    },
"repositories": [
    {
     "type": "package",
     "package": {
     "version": "2.1.1",
      "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
      "source": {
         "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git",
         "type": "git",
         "reference": "v2.1.1"
     }
   }
 }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `reference` is the real object of a repository — like a tag.
- `version` is how you call it for referencing from the `require` section.
- The one in the `require` section is a pattern to match against the `version` value. You could set it to `2.1.*` or `2.*` to make it less restrictive.

Comment: So `reference` is what ACTUALLY gets fetched. and `version` is more of a variable to be matched in the `require` section? For example -- if I put `2.0` or `master` in the `reference` section and name the `"version" : "2.1"` .. I'm fetching `2.0` or `master` and not the `2.1` tag.